# Second Normal Form Definition

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

2NF has the following definition

> A table is in 2NF if and only if it is in 1NF and ***no non-prime*** attribute is dependent on any proper subset of any candidate key of the table.

My question is why dependent attribute have to be **non-prime**? Does it mean **prime attribute** can be dependent on a proper subset of candidate key? Why in this case it won't cause redundancy? I'm thinking some example relation

```
{a,b,c,d}, if we assume {a,b}, {b,c} are two candidate keys and FD is a->c
```

Comment: A reason for the non-prime requirement is that every prime attribute in a composite key is trivially dependent on a proper subset of the key, namely itself.

Answer (score 0):

That quote is from Wikipedia (?) and I suspect it uses the reference to Codd more heavily than that for C J Date. Codd invented the concept of primary key but relational theory has moved away from the idea of 'primary' entirely.

Here's Date's more recent definition from his Relational Database Dictionary:

> Relvar [relation variable] `R` is in 2NF if and only if every nonkey attribute `A` of `R` is such that the set `{ A }` is irreducibly dependent on every key of `R` - equivalently, if and only if, for every nontrivial FD `X -> Y` that holds in `R`, (a) `X` is a superkey or (b) `Y` is a subkey or (c) `X` isn't a subkey.

Note this question risks being closed on SO because, as Date states in his Dictionary, 2NF isn't particularly interesting in practise (he includes it only for historical interest).